# Problems passing a user-defined between modules parameter

Tags: django

I am getting some odd behaviour passing an instance of Observable around. It seems to degenerate into a list and I cannot work out why.

## patterns.py

```
class Observable():

    def __init__ (self):
        self.observers = []

    def addObserver(self, observer):
        self.observers.append(observer)

    def notifyObservers(self, event):
        for observer in self.observers:
            observer.observeEvent(event)

    def __str__(self):
        print self.observers
```

## views.py

```
from patterns import Observable

def loadData ():
    '''  helper function
    '''

    print "l1"
    avoidTollObservable = Observable ()

       dataLocation = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'DATA', "links.dat").replace('\\','/')

    print "reading edges"
    edgesDict = routing._readNetworkDataFile (dataLocation, avoidTollObservable)
```

## routing.py

```
from patterns import Observable

def _readNetworkDataFile ( absFilePath , avoidTollObservable):

    print "debug:" 
    print avoidTollObservable
    print "debug end"
```

## The program produces:

```
>
> debug:
> []
> [01/May/2013 08:40:49] "GET /route/-110884.64901689/6782501.6151699/-250884.64901689/7299908.890599588/?_=1367415648664 HTTP/1.1" 500 11571
```

The last line is in mauve (indicating that there is an error,I think)

Comment: I am still unclear why this has been downvoted.

Comment: What were you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing this:

```
print avoidTollObservable
```

What you are basically doing is calling the `Observable` objects `__str__()` method

```
def __str__(self):
    print self.observers # In your code this is declared as a list
```

The `self.observers` is an empty list (its how its initialised) so your output is going to be `[]`, if you were to add a value add an item to `self.observers` before passing it to `routing._readNetworkDataFile` then the value of `print avoidTollObservable` would not be an empty list.

If you were to change `__str__()` to:

```
def __str__(self):
    print 'Object ID' + self
```

Then the output would be the id of the object and not the value of the `self.observers` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I am new to using Django in anger, I was using Ajax and did not think to pass the URL directly from the browser address box.  The lack of an error confused me for hours.